# How to avoid alert box in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to get alert only if i echo.Empty alert box display when I didn't give echo statement.I want to display alert only after the 'if' condition.

```
 $.ajax({
 type:'post',
url:'email.php',
data:{email: email},
success:function(msg){
alert(msg);         
}
});

email.php

$s=$_POST['email'];
include "config.php";
$echeck="select email from register where email='".$_POST['email']."'";
$echk=mysql_query($echeck);
$ecount=mysql_num_rows($echk);
if($ecount>=1 && $s!='0')
{
  echo "Email already exists";
}
```

Comment: check in javascript part for message length.

Comment: Well, you `alert` it after php's `if` is processed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check length of msg

```
success:function(msg){
 if (msg.length> 0) {
  alert(msg);
 }
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)

**Explanation:**

There are two conditions:

1) You are echo ing something.

2) You are not echo ing something.

In first case, you will get length of `msg` greater than `0`.

In second case, you will get length to be `0`, hence, alter will not appear.

Answer (score 3):

Try like

```
$.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url:'email.php',
  data:{email: email},
  success:function(msg){
      if($.trim(msg) != '') {
          alert(msg);        
      } 
  }
});
```

You can use `Length` also like

```
msg = $.trim(msg);
if(msg.length > 0) {
    alert(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

easy way to do it with the msg length.

### if(msg.length > 0)

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the white space coming in to the msg variable:

Try the following :
var string=msg.replace(/ +/g," ");

if(string!=""){
 alert(msg);

}